# Get children of different models in one single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

```
class Category
  has_many :images
  has_many :articles
end

class Image
  belongs_to :category
end

class Article
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I'm trying to understand what solutions there are in Rails for children of different models to be queried by the same parent?

E.g. I'd like to get all images and articles that belong to the same category and sort them all by `created_at`.

Comment: I'm thinking isn't this about [eager loading multiple association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)?

Comment: I think that loads all `Articles` in their example `Article.includes(:category, :comments)` ? But I'd love to see a working example if you have one!

Comment: In Rails example "This loads all the articles and the associated category and comments for each article". Probably in your case it could be `Category.includes(:images, :articles)` where `Category` is one with your desired ID.

Comment: I'm happy to bring clarity if something is unclear in my question. But once again, please submit an answer of a working example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'includes' in rails
Article.includes(:Category)

Comment: Mind showing an example how that could be used in this context?

Answer (score 0):

As I said it seems to me you can use [eager loading multiple associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations). In your case it could be something like this:

`Category.where(id: 2).includes(:images, :articles).sort_by(&:created_at)`

Basically you pass your desired `Category` ID and get `:images, :articles` which `belongs_to` Category with particular ID. `sort_by`probably should do the sorting thing.

This [blog post on eager loading](https://ksylvest.com/posts/2014-12-20/advanced-eager-loading-in-rails) could help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply force Active Record to bring all their dependences in a single query (afaik), regardless if is lazy/eager loading. I think your best bet is:

```
class Category
  has_many :images, -> { order(:created_at) }
  has_many :articles, -> { order(:created_at) }
end

categories = Category.includes(:images, :articles)
```

As long as you iterate categories and get their images and articles, this will make three queries, one for each table `categories`, `images` and `articles`, which is a good tradeoff for the ease of use of an ORM.
Now, if you insist to bring all that info in just one query, for sure it must be a way using [Arel](http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html), but think twice if it worths. The last choice I see is the good old SQL with:

```
query = <<-SQL 
  SELECT *, images.*, articles.* 
  FROM categories
  -- and so on with joins, orders, etc...
SQL

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

I really discourage this option as it will bring A LOT of duplicated info as you will joining three tables and it really would be a pain to sort them for your use.